# Access to Django settings using Redis

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a project on Heroku. I just recently added Redis for job queueing through Heroku's add-ons feature.

I've followed Heroku's simple [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq) to get things up and running.

I call the function like so:
`result = q.enqueue(some_other_class.some_function, some_argument)`

In `some_function` there is a call to a variable from the Django's settings file.  I follow the normal procedure, which works without Redis: `from django.conf import settings` and then get the variable `settings.THE_VARIABLE`.

When I use Redis though, that doesn't work.  I get the error:

`ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting THE_VARIABLE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings`

The `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable is set. Does the worker not have access to Django settings?  If so, how can I get around this?

Comment: @TheRealBill why the vote to close?

Comment: Are you restarting the worker after every change?

Comment: No, the worker is declared in the Procfile along with the web server like so: `web: gunicorn my_project.wsgi --log-file -
worker: python worker.py`

Answer (score 0):

Someone with the power please close this question.

It turns at that `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` was not set properly.